# How do you get the Zassenhaus formula from the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula?

Tags: lie-algebras

The BCH is given by

$e^{SX}Ye^{-sX}=Y+s[X,Y]+\frac{s^2}{2}[X,[X,Y]]+\text{...}$

How do you get to the Zassenhaus formula?

$e^{X+Y}=e^{sX}e^{sY}e^{-1/2s^2[X,Y]}\text{...}$

Comment: In what you write, this alleged "BCH" formula is not what's usually called BCH formula. In your formula $X$ belongs to the Lie algebra and $Y$ to the Lie group, so $[X,Y]$ is senseless. Also the left-hand term is in the Lie group (multiplication) and the right-hand term in the Lie algebra (addition).

Answer (score 0):

The Zassenhaus formula is a kind of dual of the Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff formula. 
On the Wikipedia page for [BCH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula), where you find the correct BCH formula, the Zassenhaus formula is also given. It is explained that "these exponents, $C_n$ in $\exp(–tX) exp(t(X+Y)) = \prod_n \exp(t_n C_n)$, follow recursively by application of the above BCH expansion." For more details see the article by
Nishimura [here](http://ma.fme.vutbr.cz/archiv/2_1/nishimura2_final.pdf), section $6$ and $7$.